# Can't make a new data type Hashable

Tags: haskell

Attempt to compile the following with ghc 7.8.2 on OS X 10.9.3

```hs
import Data.Hashable (Hashable, hash)

data Edge v = Edge v v deriving (Show)

instance (Eq v) => Eq (Edge v) where
  Edge x1 x2 == Edge y1 y2 =
    x1 == y1 && x2 == y2 || x1 == y2 && x2 == y1

instance (Hashable v) => Hashable (Edge v) where
  hash (Edge x1 x2) = (hash x1) + (hash x2)
```

fails with

```
Could not deduce (hashable-1.2.1.0:Data.Hashable.Class.GHashable
                    (GHC.Generics.Rep (Edge v)))
  arising from a use of ‘hashable-1.2.1.0:Data.Hashable.Class.$gdmhashWithSalt’
from the context (Hashable v)
  bound by the instance declaration at src/MinCut.hs:12:10-42
In the expression:
  hashable-1.2.1.0:Data.Hashable.Class.$gdmhashWithSalt
In an equation for ‘hashWithSalt’:
    hashWithSalt
      = hashable-1.2.1.0:Data.Hashable.Class.$gdmhashWithSalt
In the instance declaration for ‘Hashable (Edge v)’
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hackage docs for [Data.Hashable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable-1.2.2.0/docs/Data-Hashable.html) states that the minimal implementation of Hashable is the function `hashWithSalt` — check out the documentation under the typeclass declaration (`class Hashable a where`).

So if you change your function to `hashWithSalt`, everything should work:

```
instance (Hashable v) => Hashable (Edge v) where
  hashWithSalt s (Edge x1 x2) = s + (hash x1) + (hash x2)
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844612/why-does-data-hashtable-use-hashing-with-salt-from-data-hashable